# Getting an error in my sql query that i cant figure out how to solve

Tags: mysql, sql

so im trying to get a dynamicly generated sql query to update these lines but i keep getting an error. and i cant really understand whats wrong with it.

so.. got any clues?

Query:

```
 UPDATE abilities
 SET STR=8, DEX=8, CON=8, INT=8, WIS=8, CHA=8, Points=0 
 WHERE ID=1
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT=8, WIS=8, CHA=8, Points=0 WHERE 
ID=1' at line 2
```

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, please read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding backticks around the field `INT`.

```
UPDATE abilities
 SET STR=8, DEX=8, CON=8, `INT`=8, WIS=8, CHA=8, Points=0 
 WHERE ID=1
```

`INT` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Always add ticks to your queries.

Answer (score 3):

INT is a reserved key word and you need to backtick it

```
`INT`
```

Checkout the complete list here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html